# Tomcat 7 did not work if I put jenkins.war and nexus.war together

Tags: java, jenkins, tomcat7, nexus

all
    I use Tomcat 7. And I have set the 'set CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m' into my catalina.sh in tomcat_home/bin folder.
    Then I put jenkins.war and nexus.war into webapp/ folder. But I can not access neither of them.
    But when I remove the nexus.war, everything works well.
    Can you help me ?   My jenkins and nexus war file are both the latest.
Thanks
Steven

Here goes the logs:

```
INFO: Loaded all jobs
6136 Exception in thread "pool-8-thread-2"
6137 Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "pool-8-thread-2"
6138 Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]"
6139 Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Cata     lina]]"
6140 Exception in thread "pool-8-thread-7"
6141 Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "pool-8-thread-7"
6142 Exception in thread "pool-8-thread-3"
6143 Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "pool-8-thread-3"
6144 Exception in thread "pool-8-thread-6"
6145 Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "pool-8-thread-6"
6146 Exception in thread "pool-8-thread-4"
6147 Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "pool-8-thread-4"
6148 Exception in thread "pool-8-thread-8"
6149 Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "pool-8-thread-8"
```

Comment: Please, could you send a log with the exception or whatever you get when launching your server?

Comment: The log has been added

Comment: Exception in thread "pool-8-thread-4"
162 Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "pool-8-thread-4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add **JAVA_OPTS** in your **catalina.bat/Catalina.sh**

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx10246m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=356m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=356m"
```

**Specify the values based on your machine configuration.**